# wait for a kivy button press during a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, kivy, user-input

ive got all the data i need to show on this screen within this for loop however its just looping to the end ive been researching how to add a user input for the end of this for loop but i cant seem to find anything on it all while using kivy i need is a popup at the end so the user can basically confirm all the values and press the button to then continue the loop sorry im still a bit new to python if this is a ridiculous question thanks!
TT is a grouped pandas dataframe if that helps people understand

```
for num in range(0, amount_of_rows)
    yp = TT.iloc[[num]]
    print(yp)
    code = yp['code'].values
    description = yp['description'].values
    quantity = yp['quantity'].values
    location = yp['name2'].values
    print(code)
    print(description)
    print(quantity)
    print(location)
    self.ids.Description_one.text = str(description)
    self.ids.Product_code_one.text = str(code)
    self.ids.Quantity_one.text = str(quantity)
    self.ids.location_one.text = str(location)
```

Comment: Please indent you code trials.

Comment: sorry man first time asking on SO ill do that now

Comment: edit, i managed to do it by having a function that allows me to control the range of the loop which is then binded to a button i dont think itll be the final method but still something that controls the loop!